# PHP Multidimensional arrays keys and values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm really struggling to get my head around multi-dimensional arrays in PHP, my background is C and Java both of which I have no issues with arrays!

I'm trying to read from an SQL database a list of months, each month has a list of values corresponding to a value.

ie.

```
  2014-01-01, ("Val1", "Val2", "Val3", "Val4", "Val5"), (3, 4, 7, 5, 3)
  2014-02-01, ("Val1", "Val2", "Val3", "Val4", "Val5"), (5, 3, 6, 2, 8)
  2014-03-01, ("Val1", "Val2", "Val3", "Val4", "Val5"), (6, 5, 4, 3, 2) ...
```

I can read the values, I can split them down, but I want to be able to add those values to an array but putting the values into the correct month.

I c/Java I'd just create an array like this;

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]  - Val1 goes in here
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]  - Val2 goes in here
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]  - Val5 goes in here
```

then as I parse through the values, I'd pick up the month, and add the values I read into the correct month.

I can create the array in PHP, all I need to know, is there a blindingly obvious way that I've missed in my coffee/sleep deprived state that I can basically say something like;

If I want to change position 11 in the the 2nd array to 6 
  in C I would be this;

```
array[2][11] = 6
```

is there an equivalent to do this in PHP?

Comment: `$array[2][11] = 6;` not working for you?

Comment: It's exactly the same in PHP: `$arr[2][11] = 6`, assuming your array is numerically indexed. Please show your complete code so we can get a better understanding

Comment: $array[2][11] = 6; should work

Comment: Have you initialised your array ? PHP can't guess you are using nested array. You need to create each subarray manually before accessing them.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$array[1][11]` for the second array?

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
$myArray[2][11] = 6;
$myArray[2][12] = 7;
var_dump( $myArray ); //view structure
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick example for array access

```
$data = [
    '2014-06-24' => ['Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3'],
    '2014-06-23' => ['Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3']
];
```

In PHP you have different ways for array access. The internal iterator in arrays begins with 0. Quick and dirty you can do the following.

```
$data['2014-06-24'][0] = 'Val4';
```

So your $data array will look like

```
$data = [
    '2014-06-24' => ['Val4', 'Val2', 'Val3'],
    '2014-06-23' => ['Val1', 'Val2', 'Val3']
];
```

In a more object orientated way you can use the ArrayObject class of the StandardPhpLibrary (SPL), wich brings many methods and objtects (interfaces, iterators, etc.) for dealing with arrays.